# Index.html/index.php not found in Google CodeLabs app shell

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-apps-script, yaml, app.yaml

I was interested on on Google's web app-Shell. I've downloaded it GitHub. But I found that there is no index.html/index.php file in the whole code. All I mainly found, is the licence file, app.yaml file and app.js file. Link to that page, is [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/application-shell).
I heard,that I can install the project in my web hosting site, by using terminal. But terminal is not an option for my situation. I've stopped using Firebase, because I must have terminal for it. So, is there any other idea to install the project in my website?
Can I have a flat file, so that I could simply past the html,css, JavaScript and other media files into my server?

Comment: I cannot use terminal.

Comment: Please don't say negatively.

Comment: Don't say, like I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google web app-Shell isn't designed to have an `index.html` file. There is a views folder that has what you're looking for https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/application-shell/tree/master/server/views.

As we can see they're using handlebars for as a templating system. For example, if we look at https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/application-shell/blob/master/server/views/layouts/default.handlebars we can see that they have `{{> open-page}}` and `{{{body}}}`. If we look at handlebars [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) these partials are rendered into other views.

Essentially, there isn't a single `index.html` we can point to, but we can reconstruct the app by exploring their views.

Comment: So, I'll have to make an other app-shell like it. Right?

Comment: Ok! I'll do it. I don't have any other way.

Comment: I think a much easier way is to simply view source once you have the app running locally. This is what it got me: https://gist.github.com/jscho13/e7f7513e2f9dbe70284a196bc492dc1f

Keep in mind this doesn't have the card functionality in the top-left corner. This is probably because of how the app is designed.