# Load frame, only after clicking over "Load" button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want the `iframe` to load only when the load button is pressed.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="page.html" id="push_frame">
Frames are not supported.
        </iframe>
        <button id="load_frame">
            Load
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Usually this needs some sort of JavaScript to solve. How can I implement this?

Comment: Please show the required javascript or other codes

Comment: Start with an empty `src`, then assign in your button click event.

Comment: @Walk perfect idea. Add the necessary code (like <button onclick="document.getElementById........ as an answer, so that I could accept it as right answer.

Comment: @Walk I had an other question about GitHub. No one answered it, yet. Can you help me? Here is the link to the question page:.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46565416/8158166

Comment: Can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: @Walk no problem. I've got an answer for that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use jQuery to specify the new `attr`. It looks a lot cleaner and reduces the lines of code.

```
$('#load_frame').on('click', function() {
    $('#push_frame').attr('src', 'page.html');
});
```

I've put up a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udno5x69/).

Comment: Except all those lines of code in jQuery library ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it, store your url in `data` attribute, then retrieve it in your click event.

```js
function loadFrame() {
  var frame = document.getElementById('push_frame');
  frame.src = frame.dataset.src;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <iframe data-src="page.html" src="" id="push_frame">
Frames are not supported.
</iframe>
  <button id="load_frame" onclick="loadFrame()">
Load
</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Enough! I've got 3 ansers

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
document.getElementById('load_frame').onclick = function() {

   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.src = 'page.html';
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);

};
```

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but the idea of changing src attribute is perfect. So, I'll accept this answer.